# The textbook's way of deriving a natural deduction proof of $\vdash((\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)\leftrightarrow\phi)$ feels wrong.

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

The problem is

"Show that if we have a derivation $D$ of $\psi$ with no undischarged assumptions, then we can use it to construct, for any statement $\phi$, a derivation of $((\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)\leftrightarrow\phi)$ with no undischarged assumptions."

Here is my solution.

[image]

Below is the textbook's solution.

[image]

As you can see on the textbook solution, $\phi$ and $\psi$ cross over to another branch to introduce $\rightarrow$. The textbook didn't mention it was possible. Is the textbook solution a correct derivation of the proof?

**Update 1** : I want to solve exercises with what the author explicitly allowed in the textbook. The author wrote:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cross over to another branch."  Can you indicate which step of the textbook solution you think is in error?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury For example, $(\psi\rightarrow\phi)$ follows $\phi$ without $\psi$ above $(\psi\rightarrow\phi)$. Instead, $\psi$ appears on the left branch. The textbook didn't explicitly allow such an operation.

Comment: I don't follow.  It's certainly the case that you can deduce $A \to B$ from $B$, and in fact you've used in this in your own proof.

Comment: I didn't deduce $A\rightarrow B$ from $B$. I used $(\rightarrow I)$ rule from the textbook. I can delete an assumption by putting it in the antecedent of a new $\rightarrow$.

Comment: There are no "strange tricks"; a allowed way to use $\to$-intro is to discharge a "non-existent" assumption, i.e.; $\psi \vdash \phi \to \psi$ (like in the two top-right branches). This corresponds to the fact that $\psi \to (\phi \to \psi)$ is a *tautology*; thus, assuming $\psi$, by *modus ponens* $(\phi \to \psi)$ follows, for $\phi$ whatever.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I already knew it was possible to infer $A\to B$ from $B$. Assuming you're correct, the textbook isn't then exactly friendly to beginners or self-learners. Although the book isn't advertised as beginner-friendly, a beginner-friendly textbook should explain concepts before using it. The book didn't explain about how non-existent assumptions are allowed to be discharged. Also, as I said in **update 1**, I wanted to do only what the author explicitly allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error; an allowed way to use $\to$-intro is to discharge a "non-existent" assumption, i.e.:

> $\psi \vdash \phi \to \psi$,

as in the two top-right branches.

This corresponds to the fact that $\psi \to (\phi \to \psi)$ is a *tautology*; thus, assuming $\psi$, by modus ponens $(\phi \to \psi)$ follows, for $\phi$ whatever.

See the textbbok's comment on the rule, [page 17](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA17):

> The rule is still correctly applied if we do not discharge all of them; in fact the rule is correctly applied even if $\phi$ is not an assumption of $D$ at all, so that there is nothing to discharge. Example 2.4.4 ([page 19](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA19)) will illustrate these points.

Answer (score 2):

There's no crossing over.   On one branch $\psi$ is true from the derivation (D).   On the other branch, $\phi$ is assumed, then later discharged.

It is just making use of an *unusual* form of conditional introduction; if something is true, then anything will imply it is true.   $p\vdash (q\to p)$

Where as the *usual* form is the deduction theorem: $(p\vdash q)\vdash p\to q$

$$\begin{array}{l|l:l}
1 & \psi & D\vdash \psi
\\
2 & \phi\to \psi & 1, {\to}\mathsf I
\\ \hdashline
3 & \quad \phi & \textsf{Assume }\phi
\\
4 & \quad \psi\to \phi & 3,{\to}\mathsf I
\\
5 & \quad \phi\leftrightarrow \psi & 2, 4, {\leftrightarrow}\mathsf I
\\ \hline
6 & \phi \to (\phi\leftrightarrow \psi) & 5, {\to}\mathsf I~ (\textsf{DT Discharges Assumption of }\phi)
\end{array}$$

$$\require{enclose}\require{cancel}\enclose{circle}{A}\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{D}{\psi}}{\phi\to\psi}{{\to}\mathsf I}\quad\dfrac{\cancel[color=red]{\color{blue}\phi}^{\enclose{circle}A}}{\psi\to\phi}{{\to}\mathsf I}}{\phi\leftrightarrow\psi}{{\leftrightarrow}\mathsf I}}{\color{blue}\phi\to(\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)}{{\to}\textsf{I (DT)}}$$

Comment: If you like, prove this version of the deduction rule as a theorem and call it $(\to I')$, then.

Comment: We assume $q$ to be true, and because $p$ is given as true, we infer that $q$ implies $p$ (discharging the assumption via $\to$ I).$${p}{\dfrac{\dfrac{q}{p}}{q\to p}}$$ $\therefore p\vdash q\to p$

Comment: The problem is that the $(\rightarrow I)$ natural deduction rule from the textbook doesn't allow $p\vdash(q\rightarrow p)$. The author didn't prohibit doing it, but he/she didn't exactly allow it, either. I want to solve exercises only with what the author allowed explicitly.

Comment: @crocket Well then you have to explain to us what the author allowed explicitly.

Comment: @mrp I added what the author allowed as an update to the question.

Comment: @crocket Your update contains the answer.  $$\dfrac{\cancel \phi \\ D \\ \psi}{\phi\to \psi}{{\to}\mathsf I}$$  We assume $\phi$, then since the derivation entails $\psi$, we infer that $\phi\to\psi$ (by implication introduction).

Comment: The textbook's solution doesn't contain the equivalent of the cancelled $\phi$. It is hard to accept them as the same thing without further assumptions.